# error in code vb.net import data from access to sdf

Tags: database, vb.net, sqlcommand, sdf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maWeh.png)I am using a SQL Server Compact 3.5 database file (.sdf) in vb.net

> There was an error parsing the query. [Token line number,Token line offset,,Token in error,,]

```
Dim flag As Boolean
    Dim flag2 As Boolean
    Me.OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "mdb files (*.mdb)|"
    Me.OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "mdb files (*.mdb)|*.mdb|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    flag2 = (Me.OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK)
    If flag2 Then
        flag = (Operators.CompareString(FileSystem.Dir(Me.OpenFileDialog1.FileName, FileAttribute.Normal), "", False) <> 0)
    End If
    Dim myConnectionStringMDB As String = "provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;" & "data source=" & Me.OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    Dim myConnectionStringSQL As String = "Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5;" & "Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\Archive.sdf"
    Using conSQL As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(), conMDB As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection()
        conSQL.ConnectionString = myConnectionStringSQL
        conSQL.Open()
        conMDB.ConnectionString = myConnectionStringMDB
        conMDB.Open()
        Using cmdSQL As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(), cmdMDB As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand()
            cmdMDB.CommandType = Data.CommandType.Text
            cmdMDB.Connection = conMDB
            cmdMDB.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [student]"
            Dim daMDB = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmdMDB)
            Dim dt = New Data.DataTable()
            daMDB.Fill(dt)
            For Each dr As Data.DataRow In dt.Rows
                ' change row status from "Unchanged" to "Added" so .Update below will insert them
                dr.SetAdded()
            Next
            cmdSQL.CommandType = Data.CommandType.Text
            cmdSQL.Connection = conSQL
            cmdSQL.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [student]"
            Dim daSQL = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmdSQL)
            Dim cbuilderMDB = New OleDbCommandBuilder(daSQL)
            cbuilderMDB.QuotePrefix = "["
            cbuilderMDB.QuoteSuffix = "]"
            daSQL.Update(dt)
        End Using
        conSQL.Close()
        conMDB.Close()
    End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of the extra boolean variables `flag` and `flag2` and just tested the values directly.

I divided the `Using` blocks into 2 blocks so the first group of objects can be closed and disposed before the next group starts their work.

I shortened the code by passing properties directly to the constructors of the objects where possible. `DataAdapter` and `StringBuilder` also expose a `.Dispose` method so I included them in the `Using` blocks.

```
daMDB.AcceptChangesDuringFill = False
```

This line of code allows the `.DataRowState` to remain as `Added` (normally it is changed to `Unchanged` by the `.Fill` method) so, the `DataTable` will be ready to add all the records to the second table without the loop.

I don't believe that student is a reserved word in either database so I removed the square brackets.

Both the `.Fill` and the `.Update` methods of the `DataAdapter` will `.Open` and `.Close` the connection if they find the connection closed. If they find it open they will leave it open. So, closing the connection is not necessary. Also the `End Using` closes and disposes all objects included in the Using portion (first line including commas) of the block.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "mdb files (*.mdb)|*.mdb|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    Dim MDBFile As String
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(OpenFileDialog1.FileName) Then
        MDBFile = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim myConnectionStringMDB As String = "provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;" & "data source=" & MDBFile
    Dim myConnectionStringSQL As String = "Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5;" & "Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\Archive.sdf"
    Dim dt = New Data.DataTable()
    Using conMDB As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(myConnectionStringMDB),
            cmdMDB As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM student", conMDB),
            daMDB As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmdMDB)
        daMDB.AcceptChangesDuringFill = False
        daMDB.Fill(dt)
    End Using
    Using conSQL As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(myConnectionStringSQL),
                cmdSQL As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM student", conSQL),
                daSql As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmdSQL),
                cbuilderMDB As New OleDbCommandBuilder(daSql)
        daSql.Update(dt)
    End Using
End Sub
```